# Django how do you build it into a model check that if User read articles or not?

Tags: python, django, model

First, I have a user model and a article model in Django And each user can write/read any article

What i need to

1. want a list of articles that each user has not read.
2. want to check the list of people who have read about a certain article and the list of people who have not read it.

How can i build or modify a model?

my models are here

Cheers

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = UserManager()

class article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(None of this is tested, but should help)

I would look to add a ManyToMany relation between `User` and `article` that tracks the articles read by the User:

```
class User(...):
   ...
   articles_read = models.ManyToManyField(article, related_name="read_by_user")
```

Then you can do something like this to record someone having read a particular article:

```
a_user.articles_read.add(article)
```

> I want a list of articles that each user has not read.

```
article.objects.exclude(read_by_user=user)
```

> want to check the list of people who have read about a certain article

```
User.objects.filter(articles_read=article)
```

> and the list of people who have not read it.

```
User.objects.exclude(articles_read=article)
```

The docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) including a note on 'through models' which will let you store more info about the user<->article relationship, such as *when* the user read the article, for instance. Indeed, Rajat's example of a `Read` class could be used as your through model, pretty much

PS: I would rename your `article` class to be `Article` now, to make life easier - the convention in Python is that a class has a capital first letter while an instance of a class is all lower case

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. not sure if it is the best method or not, but do give it a try.

I would create a new model named 'read'

```
Class Read(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, what you would do is, whenever an article is read you create add a new entry for example:

```
read = Read.objects.create(user=user, article=article)
# you need to provide the user and the article objects
read.save()
```

What this statement would do is store that the user `user` has read the article `article`

Now to filter the users who have read the article you may do

```
Read.objects.filter(article=**the article you wan't**)
```

To check the articles list of people who have not read it would be the users who are not there in the above filter.

---

Now to check the list of articles which each user has read would be

```
Read.objects.filter(user=**the user you wan't**)
```

to check those articles which the user has not read would be those who are not there in this filter, you can use the `exclude()` method / function for this.

hope it helped you.